# Set JavaScript Object value with a function

Tags: javascript

Im trying to set an Object value with a function.
essentially, im trying to calculate the total values in an object up to a certain point, which is the `limit` variable im passing to the `calculateTotal` function.

seems like im doing it wrong, any suggestions?

```js
var sc = 0.75
com = 2197.63,
  user_input = 400,
  f11_total = 0;

var v = {
  "a": com,
  "b": (com * 0.06 * sc),
  "c": (com * 0.09 * sc),
  "d": (215.54 * Math.pow(sc, 2)),
  "e": (299.36 * sc),
  "f": 328.76,
  "g": ((com * 0.048) * (user_input / 400)),
  "h": (com * 0.01),
  "3.6": 0.036,
  "total": function() {
    calculateTotal(3.6);
  }
};

function calculateTotal(limit) {
  for (var k in v) {
    if (k == limit) return (f11_total * v[k]);
    f11_total += v[k];
  }
}

console.log(calculateTotal(3.6));
```

thanks!

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: `"total": calculateTotal(3.6)`

Comment: This sounds like a pretty good chance to use `get`. I realize this question is "complete" but decided to throw an alternative in the ring anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of the `total` member is getting set to the function you have defined, not it's return value.

As @Santi points out, we can't reference `v` inside `calculateTotal` until `v` has finished being declared.

An approach here could be to populate `total` after `v` has been declared like this:

```
var v = {
  "a": com,
  "b": (com * 0.06 * sc),
  "c": (com * 0.09 * sc),
  "d": (215.54 * Math.pow(sc, 2)),
  "e": (299.36 * sc),
  "f": 328.76,
  "g": ((com * 0.048) * (user_input / 400)),
  "h": (com * 0.01),
  "3.6": 0.036  
};
v.total = calculateTotal(3.6);
```

Comment: i tried that but for some reason im getting an `undefined` result, what am i missing?

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink I believe OP wants this to return `116.88649793999998`, however the example above will return `0`. And `k == limit` will *always* evaluate to true. It's the property before `"total"`.

Comment: @Santi thanks, I missed the return statement in there. I updated my answer

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink I believe that `v` is `undefined` because you're referencing `v` inside it's own initialization.

Comment: once `k == limit` is true (and i check, it returns true just once), the function is suppose to return 116.886... if i call the function from outside the object, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The primary issue is that you're returning a *function* instead of an actual value.

---

[Jonathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45848349/2026606) is concise and correct, however I figured I'd supply you with a modern alternative using [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

It requires no manipulation/initialization of the object, is entirely self-contained, and will recalculate if/when the object is modified.

```js
var sc = 0.75
com = 2197.63,
  user_input = 400;

var v = {
  "a": com,
  "b": (com * 0.06 * sc),
  "c": (com * 0.09 * sc),
  "d": (215.54 * Math.pow(sc, 2)),
  "e": (299.36 * sc),
  "f": 328.76,
  "g": ((com * 0.048) * (user_input / 400)),
  "h": (com * 0.01),
  "3.6": 0.036,
  get total() {
    var f11_total = 0;
    for (var k in this) {
      if (k == 3.6) return (f11_total * this[k]);
      f11_total += this[k];
    }
  }
}

console.log("v.total = " + v.total);
v.f = 100;
console.log("f changed to 100");
console.log("v.total = " + v.total);
```